# Not valid datetime error due to wrong fomat of datetime in calender extender

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to store **DateTime**  value in database field **"Date"** whose datatype is DateTime.

But I am getting below error:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

My code is as below:

```
dr["Date"] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

`dr["Date"]` gives me database column name "Date" whose datatype is datetime in my database.
I am getting DateTime value using **calender extender for txtDate textbox**,
then converting that value to **DateTime** datatype so that I can insert that value to database table.
 But why am i getting above error when I am giving correct datatype.

Comment: What is the text in the textbox? the error is very informative

Comment: You have our answer in the Error. Whatever is in txtDate.Text is not a valid DateTime.

Comment: What is the value of `txtDate.Text` ?

Comment: txtDate.Text is simply not valid in your case.. Try giving a hardcoded value and check

Comment: As I told already, value of txtDate.text is 2013-00-03, which i am getting using calender extender

Comment: 2013-00-03 is not a valid DateTime.

Comment: 2013-**00**-03 - What day (or month) has the value 0?

Comment: You did not tell that. And what month is `00`?

Comment: Is that a custom format? (YYYYhhmm)?

Comment: I think I got my answer, Calender extender is giving me wrong month

Comment: @Sayse - good point. Maybe the format is `yyyy-mm-dd` when it *should* be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: I am getting 2013-00-03 using calender extender, which is clearly wrong date , I am using Format="yyyy-mm-dd" for calender extender

Comment: `mm` is minutes; `MM` is month.

Comment: @Corak - Excellent catch. You should post that as an answer :)

Comment: Hey! I caught that :P (I agree with tim tho)

Comment: Sorry @Sayse - you did point out the format could be the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share what exactly I was doing wrong, although it will make me look like a fool. But hopefully it will help someone else with the same problem.

I was giving wrong format for the calendar extender, as shown below:

> yyyy-mm-dd

The correct format should have been:

> yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: +1 for posting the answer.  I don't think it makes you look like a fool.  Sometimes it just takes a second set (or more) of fresh eyes to catch the problem - every developer has their moment(s) of "I just can't figure out this error". :)  Don't forget to accept your answer so you get the rep credit for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some Code to catch something like this and don't cause an Exeption:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out dateValue)) 
{
      dr["Date"] = dateValue;
}
else
{
      Debug.Write("TextBox Value '{0}' isn't a valid datetime.", txtDate.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22) to extract the `DATETIME` based on format...

```
            DateTime yourDate;
            var formats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd" };
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out yourDate))
            {
                dr["Date"] = yourDate;
            }
            else
            {
                // Do with Invalid DateTime
            }
```